# How do I query the results obtained from Firebase realtime database for ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am integrating the firebase realtime database into my ionic 3 application. Currently, I am able to do the basic Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete directly from my realtime database. However, I want to query the data I retrieved from the realtime database (similar to SQL querying - WHERE, ORDER BY, etc).

Currently, here are my codes:

home.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.itemRef = afDB.object('Restaurant');
      this.ref = this.afDB.database.ref('/Restaurant');
      this.getDetails();
  }

getDetails(){
    this.afDB.list('/Restaurant').snapshotChanges().subscribe((res) => {
      let tempArray:any = [];

      res.forEach((ele) => {
        console.log(ele.payload.val());
        tempArray.push(ele.payload.val())
      });
      this.displayDetail = tempArray;
      console.log(this.displayDetail);
    })
}
```

My goal is to query the getDetails() method to return the data that I want from the realtime database.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a query in firebase, then try the following:

```
    this.afDB.list('/Restaurant', ref => ref.orderByChild('food').equalTo('chicken')).snapshotChanges().subscribe((res) => {
      let tempArray:any = [];

      res.forEach((ele) => {
        console.log(ele.payload.val());
        tempArray.push(ele.payload.val())
      });
      this.displayDetail = tempArray;
      console.log(this.displayDetail);
    })
```

This will return the data where node `food` is equal to `chicken`, you can check here regarding query:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md